# Rational Appln Deb IBM 7.5.4

Tags: java, ibm-rad, ibm-rational

I am using RAD 7.5.4 IDE  many a times when i type something in a java file, it gets hung and i have to close it and restart it again. also i wanted to clean all the ears and make my RAD fast. any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try changing the JVM startup parameters for RAD?

-Xms    initial java heap size
-Xmx    maximum java heap size
-Xmn    the size of the heap for the young generation

Also, it happens to a lot of people that Eclipse/RAD just hangs and you have to wait for it. (ex-colleague used to call it the white toolbar of death in eclipse)

Comment: how do i change heap size from RAD